# Marketing Agreement.

Tags: contract-law

We are company A. We have a marketing Agreement with company B to market and sell all of their technologies. Company B has a JV with company C for a technology. Do we need a new agreement to include company C or can we market this technology due to our agreement with company B?

Comment: In this context are you using JV for Joint Venture?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the exact terms of the agreement between A and B. Does it say that it covers products produced as part of a joint venture? It may well also depend on the exact terms of the agreement between B and C.

In any case, A should discuss it with A's own lawyer or legal department. Also, A should probably discuss it with B. If B agrees that A can market the technology created by the JV, many problems go away..